# Margins and anchors not working good in Qt, QML

Tags: qt, qml, margin

I'm new at QML and I have a very confusing situation.
So, this is my main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {

    id:rootWin
    visible: true
    width: 350
    height: 330

    ConnectBox
    {
        id:boxConnect

        MouseArea
        {
            id: connectMouse
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: boxConnect
        }
    }

Rectangle {
        id: randomRec
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/6
//        x: 50
        anchors.top: boxConnect.bottom
//        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        border.color: "dimgray"
        border.width: 5
        radius: 14
    }
}
```

ConnectBox.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: connectRec
    width: parent.width/2
    height: parent.height/6
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    border.color: "dimgray"
    border.width: 5
    radius: 14
}
```

I want it to be `randomRec` below `boxConnect`, so it does but it is all left and it only moves when I put for example `x: 50` but its not convenient for every size of the window.

Comment: Can you explain how you _do_ want it to move as well?

Comment: randomRec IS below boxConnect but it starts on the left side, I want it to be at center, just like boxConnect, only below it

Answer (score 1):

First off: I'd advise to put the anchors that are related to each other all on the same file.

But to get the `randomRec` to center below the `connectBox` you should use the following anchors:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect1
    width: 100
    height: 200
    color: "red"

    anchors.centerIn: parent
}

Rectangle {
    id: rect2
    width: 75
    height: 50
    color: "yellow"

    anchors.top: rect1.bottom
    anchors.horizontalCenter: rect1.horizontalCenter
}
```

So I guess you where almost there, with the `horizontalCenter: parent` line, which should have `.horizontalCenter` as well. However, I anchored it on `rect1` since that is what you want (let's say you might want to move the boxConnect in the future... you would have to find all of the references)